# Зарегистрировать сертификат разработчика iOS

Tags: ios, мобильная-разработка

Собираюсь регистрировать сертификат разработчика *iOS*. Проблема в том, что пока не приходилось сталкиваться с оплатой валютой, отличной от рублей, соответственно карты подходящей нет. Подскажите, каким образом можно оплатить? Вариант зарегистрировать виртуальную карту на *QIWI* и оплатить с помощью нее прокатит?

Answer (score 2):

Я регистрировался когда, платил обычной визой классик. Думаю без проблем прокатит и виртуальная виза от киви например.
Конвертация в доллары происходит по курсу вашего банка.

Comment: Немного дополню. Обычно, проблем при оплате любой картой не возникает. Некоторые банки вводят ограничения на валютные операции. Просто попробуйте оплатить, если не получится, то обратитесь в службу поддержки банка. Там подскажут, как можно оплатить. В худшем случае придется попросить оплатить друга :)